# Outlook plugin with dovecot

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get a plugin made for outlook that will do out of office with dovecot as its backend using a sieve. Can anyone advise how the plugin will need to logi on the linux box to write to the user`s sieve file. AS the mailserver connects to Active Directory,there is no local users created. All users are from ad and can`t log on the linux box itself.

Cheers for the advise.

rajbps

Comment: Are the user's mailbox on dovecot, and Outlook client is connecting via IMAP and SMTP?  I don't believe this is a supported scenario for Outlook Web Add-ins.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#requirement-sets-supported-by-exchange-servers-and-outlook-clients .  Maybe you want to create VSTO/COM style add-in.

Comment: Hiya are you able to gude me by any chance pls on how to archive that pls

Comment: Sorry rajbps, I'm not as well versed on the VSTO/COM side.  Because you added tags for both the old-style and new-style add-ins, it may have dampened the responses.  You could try re-formulating your question and asking with only the 'outlook-addin' tag.